# putBytes() vs putFile() for uploading images

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to upload images from app to firebase storage and there is fragment in app where I want to
show images on server in recycler view. Should I use putBytes() or putFile()? such that when I display images using recylerview in OnBind() function images load faster.

Comment: I believe that neither method will be faster for loading later and these methods both exist as a convenience to make it easier to put data in storage depending on what you're currently working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`putFile()` is just a convenience method for automatically reading the file and using `putBytes()` to upload it.  Either way, the speed of the upload is limited by the speed of the device's connection to Cloud Storage.